# How to convert an audio file (mp3 or acc) to split stereo files?

Tags: java, android, audio

I have an audio file. It can be in any format for example say mp3. I have to split it into left and right channel(stereo type). How to do this in android? Please help.

Comment: I don't see any effort from your side. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to android.I have been searching about this but did nt find any android resource about this.If anyone know this please help.

Answer (score 0):

When loading a music using MediaPlayer its on stereo already. You can set the volume of left and right according to what you need.

mediaPlayer.volume(set left, set right)

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample_song);
    mediaPlayer.volume(1,1);//(volume left, volume right)
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```